# Can a local page accept text value and open new tab at Internet URL with value as parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-url

An Internet site has URL like `www.manyresultpages.net/cgi-bin/search.cgi?recnum=7777&`

Can I make my Dad a local static html page (for his PC) with one input field and a submit button, that will modify the above URL, replace "7777" with the input text and open the new URL in a new tab on button click?

I'm HTML-challenged, googled for 45 mins without getting far.  Did learn jsfiddle.net is down. Can load jQuery if that would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use `method="get"` in the form to place the form data in the URL, use an input field with `name="recnum"` to get the right name for the form data, and use `target="_blank"` in the form to open the page in a new window/tab:

```
<form method="get" target="_blank">
  <input type="text" name="recnum"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Note that you can't control whether the page is opened in a new window or a new tab, as that is a user preference in the browser.

Comment: Looks wonderful!  But where does the static part of the URL go?  I've revised the question to clarify that it's not my site--I only control the local page I'm hoping to use to link to it.

Comment: You can use an `url` attribute in the `form` tag, but the default is to use the same URL as the current page.